# What is the simplest and most efficient function to return a sublist based on an index list?

Tags: python, list

Say I have a list `l`:

```
['a','b','c','d','e']
```

and a list of indexes `idx`:

```
[1,3]
```

What is the simplest and most efficient function that will return:

```
['b','d']
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is an option using a list comprehension:

```
[v for i, v in enumerate(l) if i in idx]
```

This will be more efficient if you convert `idx` to a set first.

An alternative with `operator.itemgetter`:

```
import operator
operator.itemgetter(*idx)(l)
```

As noted in comments, `[l[i] for i in idx]` will probably be your best bet here, unless `idx` may contain indices greater than the length of `l`, or if `idx` is not ordered and you want to keep the same order as `l`.

Comment: I would say its better to do `[main_list[i] for i in idx]` since idx will almost certainly be the shorter of the lists

Comment: I definitely understand preferring the other solution, but [a downvote here seems excessive](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-down).

Answer (score 13):

Try using this:

```
[l[i] for i in idx]
```

Comment: Simple and efficient. This is the best answer IMO.

Comment: I concur ... shorter iteration than other one and clearer than item getter (at least imho)

Comment: +1 Instead of iterating over the (assumably larger) list l, this iterates over the (assumably shorter) list of indices to get. Brilliant!

Comment: "Brilliant" is overselling it IMHO. This way around seems quite a bit more obvious to me.

Answer (score 7):

You want `operator.itemgetter`.

In my first example, I'll show how you can use `itemgetter` to construct a callable which you can use on any indexable object:

```
from operator import itemgetter
items = itemgetter(1,3)
items(yourlist)  #('b', 'd')
```

Now I'll show how you can use argument unpacking to store your indices as a list

```
from operator import itemgetter
a = ['a','b','c','d','e']
idx = [1,3]
items = itemgetter(*idx)
print items(a)  #('b', 'd')
```

Of course, this gives you a `tuple`, not a `list`, but it's trivial to construct a list from a tuple if you really need to.

Comment: probably the most efficient answer ... not sure iterating over idx in a list comprehension is probably fast