# What is the most efficient way to return a subset of a list

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I am parsing a large amount of binary data that has been put in a list of lists:

```
row = [1,2,3...]                # list of many numbers
data = [row1,row2,row3...]      # a list of many rows

list_of_indices = [1,5,13,7...] # random list of indices. Always shorter than row
                                #This list won't change after creation
```

I would like to return a row containing only the elements listed in `list_of_indices`:

```
subset_row = [row(index) for index in list_of_indices]
```

My question:

Would `subset_row` contain copies of each element that is returned (i.e would `subset_row` be a completely new list in memory) or would `subset_row` contain references to the original data. Note that the data will not be modified so I think it may not even matter..

Also, is there a more efficient way to do this? I will have to iterate over thousands of rows..

This is somewhat covered here, but its not specific enough in terms of what is returned.
[What is the simplest and most efficient function to return a sublist based on an index list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12465403/what-is-the-simplest-and-most-efficient-function-to-return-a-sublist-based-on-an)

Comment: A subset as in containing only elements from the list, or as in a slice of the list?

Comment: What will you do with the new lists.  Will you only be using them once?  Is a generator a possibility?

Comment: are you up to use `numpy`? It would be something like: `subset_row=row[list_of_indices]` if `row` and `list_of_indices`ar both `numpy.ndarray` objects

Comment: So, `row1`, `row2`, etc are each lists of many numbers? What do the indices in `list_of_indices` index, a row in `data` or an item in a row?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it should be

```
[row[index] for index in list_of_indexes]
```

(or just `map(list_of_indexes.__getitem__, row)`)

Secondly, there is no way in Python to have a reference/pointer to an object; or, in other words, everything is already a reference anyway. So what this mean is that, effectively, in the case of `int`s, there is basically no difference; in the case of more "heavyweight" objects, you get references automatically because nothing is ever implicitly copied in Python.

**NOTE:** if you `row` contains a large amount of data, and `list_of_indexes` is also a long list, you might want to consider lazy evaluation (a.k.a. generators and generator expressions in Python):

```
subset_row = (row[index] for index in list_of_indexes)
```

now you can either iterate over `subset_row` without having to evalute/read all of the values in the sequence in memory, or you can just consume the sequence one by one using:

```
first = next(subset_row)
second = next(subset_row)
# etc
```

**Futhermore**, since you also mention a "list of lists" and have `data = [row1, row2, ...]` in your code example, I suspect you might want to apply that operation accross multiple lists simultaneously:

```
indices = [3, 7, 123, ...]
data = [<row1>, <row2>, ...]
rows = [[row[i] for i in indices] for row in data]
```

or for laziness of the outer list:

```
rows = ([row[i] for i in indices] for row in data)
```

or for both:

```
row = ((row[i] for i in indices) for row in data)
```

Comment: I think the OP was asking if it was building new lists, not if they were new ints

Comment: @cmd: I think not: he said *"copies of EACH ELEMENT that is returned"* and *"contain REFERENCES to the original data"*. —however, my comment about generators also covers that in a way.

Comment: Yeah, that was a bit confusing, because in his example he has just `subset_row = ...`; in any case, my answer should now cover all cases.